# How to trim an option string in a Slick column mapping when using Play Scala

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, slick-2.0

What is the correct way, and where is the correct place, to trim a value from a fixed character database column when using the Play framework with Slick?

The reason I want to trim the string is that the database schema specifies a `character(40)` column type rather than a `character varying` type.

I have this case class:

```
case class Test(id: Long, trimMe: Option[String])
```

I have this Slick table relation:

```
class Tests(tag: Tag) extends Table[Test](tag, "test") {

  def id     = column[Long  ]("test_id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def trimMe = column[String]("trim_me"                         )

  def * = (id, trimMe) <> (Test.tupled, Test.unapply _)

}
```

I have this test class with a JSON mapping:

```
object TrimTest {

  implicit val testWrite = new Writes[Test] {
    def writes(test: Test) = Json.obj(
      "id"   -> test.id    ,
      "trim" -> test.trimMe
    )}
}
```

This all works but returns a space-padded string.

I tried a few variations of trimming in the JSON mapper:

```
object TrimTest {

  implicit val testWrite = new Writes[Test] {
    def writes(test: Test) = Json.obj(
      "id"    -> test.id                              ,
      "trim1" -> test.trimMe.map(_.trim)              ,
      "trim2" -> test.trimMe.fold("") {_.trim}        ,
      "trim3" -> test.trimMe.map(_.trim).getOrElse("")
    )}
}
```

`trim1` above works, but returns `null` when the optional value is not present.

`trim2` does work for all cases, but I have seen it stated in various places that `map` then `getForElse` is "more idiomatic Scala" than using `fold`.

`trim3` is just past the limit of my current understanding of Scala and shows my intent but does not compile.

The compilation error in the case of `trim3` is:

> type mismatch;
>   found   : Object
>   required: play.api.libs.json.Json.JsValueWrapper

I can certainly live with using `fold`, but what is the usual way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about getting the value and then trimming?

```
scala> val strOpt = Option("Some string not trimmed    ")
strOpt: Option[String] = Some(Some string not trimmed    )

scala> strOpt.getOrElse("").trim
res0: String = Some string not trimmed

scala> val strNone = Option(null)
strNone: Option[Null] = None

scala> strNone.getOrElse("").trim
res2: String = ""
```

Edit:

You have a `Test` row  which is a case class with two fields, `id` and `trimMe`, you want to map this class to a JSON but the problem is you also want to `trim` it a the `trimeMe` field.

If you have a `Column[String]`, from the `Slick` perspective it means a non optional field, but your case class *has* an optional field, either both (`Test` and `Tests`) have an optional `trimMe` field (that means a nullable column) or they don't (that means that the column is mandatory).

In the end the case class you have is the representation of a row you have in your database and that's what Slick queries return(*), it should reflect your schema declaration.

For the `trim` problem

- if `trimMe` is a `Column[Option[String]]` your case class has `trimMe: Option[String]` so you can `getOrElse` and be sure to return a `String` and then `trim`,

  ```
  val someString = Option("some String  ")
  someString.getOrElse("").trim
  ```
- if `trimMe` is a `Column[String]` you case class has `trimMe: String`, then just wrap it in an `Option`, then `getOrElse` and then `trim`:

  ```
  val str = "some other string  "
  Option(str).getOrElse("").trim
  ```

In this way wether it's a `None` or `Some` no exception is thrown.

(*) Not always, you can have queries which return columns instead of whole rows.

Comment: I think my problem is more to do with precisely where and how it should be done in a typical Play/Scala/Slick/JSON architecture. It's still not clear to me from your answer how I should do that.

Comment: Your edit pointed me at the solution, thanks. I can simply do test.trimMe.getOrElse("").trim. I thought I tried that earlier, but then I tried a lot of different ways...

Answer (score 0):

what about simple logic with pattern matching:

```
def trimOptionString(in: Option[String]): Option[String] = in.map(_.trim) match {
  case None => None
  case Some("") => None
  case Some(x) => Some(x)
}
```